# does probability change when if parts of the combination are already chosen (see full Q)

Tags: probability

Bag “A” contains an envelope and it is known that the envelope is red. A second envelope is chosen from another bag “B” where there are 4 green, 5 yellow and 6 red cards. This envelope is added to bag “A” and an envelope is drawn at random from bag “A” now. It comes out to be a red envelope. What is the probability that the envelope remaining in the bag is also red.

Comment: what I was getting :
Step 1 : 
adding random envelope to bag "A":
total 15 possibilities:
6 both red and 9 red and non-red

Step 2 :
one is chosen and it turns out to be red :

12 cases where the other envelope is red (2 for each red-red case) and
9 cases where the other is non red

Therfore probability that the envelope remaining in the bag is also red is 12/(12 + 9) = 4/7

Comment: Your reasoning looks good to me.  If you want to be more formal about it, write out Bayes' Theorem.  You have a total probability of drawing red equal to $\frac 35\times \frac 12+\frac 25\times 1=\frac 7{10}$ and the contribution of the red-red case is $\frac 25$ so the answer is the ratio $\frac {2/5}{7/10}=\frac 47$.  This is, of course, more or less equivalent to what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

$X = \text{selecting a red envelope from bag B} = \text{bag A has 2 red envelopes}\\P(X) = \frac 25$

$Y = \text{selecting a red envelope from bag A after transfer}\\P(Y) = P(Y|X)P(X)+P(Y|X^C)P(X^C)=\frac 22\times\frac 25 +\frac 12\times\frac 35 = \frac 7{10}$

$Z = \text{other envelope red when red selected}\\\therefore P(Z) = P(X|Y)=\frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}=\frac{2/5}{7/10}= \frac{4}{7}$

is an unnecessary formalization of your and @lulu's reasoning that I posted anyway because I didn't see your comments until too late lol.

I say $X|Y \equiv Z$ since the only times the other envelope is red, given a red envelope is selected, is when two red envelopes are in bag A.